# When does a function not have a limit?

Tags: limits

What are the cases in which a function does not have a limit? With the exception of piecewise functions, it seems like a function can always be said to have a limit, since I think the value of a function can always be said to lie in the interval $(A-\varepsilon,A+\varepsilon)$.

> A function $f(x)$ approaches a limit $A$ as $x$ approaches $a$ if, and
> only if, for each positive number $\epsilon$ there is another,
> $\delta$, such that whenever $0 < |x-a| < \delta $
> we have $|f(x) - A| < \epsilon$. That is, when $x$ is near $a$ (within a > distance $\delta$ from it), $f(x)$ is near $A$
> (within a distance $\epsilon$ from it).
> In symbols we write $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = A$.

Comment: Ummm... $\sin x$?  $\sin^2 x$? ....

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What is $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \sin x$?  (Try graphing, to get an idea...)

Comment: Christina, take e.g. tangent function.

Comment: From the limit definition, $\varepsilon$ can be any positive number, right?

Comment: What does a function having a limit mean?  Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0&\text{if }x\in \mathbb Q\\ 1&\text{if }x\not \in Q\end{cases}$.  Does $f$ have a limit? What about $f(x)= 2x^2 + 3$ if $x \ne 6$ and $f(6) =-5689$.  What is $\lim_{x\to 6}f(x)$?  And what do you mean that the value of a function lies in $(A -\epsilon, A+\epsilon)$? What is $A$ and what is $\epsilon$.  What if the value *doesn't* lie in there?

Comment: "From the limit definition, ε can be any positive number, right? "  But it must be true for *ALL* positive numbers.  Not just one single positive number.

Comment: I think I understand now. There is a difference between the word "any" which allows for choosing a large number, and "each" which means all numbers, 'large' and 'small.'

Comment: Christina, I have edited your question to remove the [functional-analysis] tag. Please read its description to be better informed of its meaning.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a classic example, consider the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sin(1/x) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
The limit $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ does not exist because there is no value of $A$ that works. In particular, define the sequences
$$
x_n = \frac1{2\pi n}, \quad y_n = \frac 1{2 \pi (n + 1/2)}.
$$
Note that we have $f(x_n) = 0$ and $f(y_n) = 1$ for all $n$, but both sequences $x_n,y_n$ approach zero. Now, take $\epsilon = 1/4$, and consider any possible $\delta > 0$ (as small as you'd like). We can always find an $n$ so that $0 < |x_n - 0| < \delta$, so the limit $A$ (if it exists) should satisfy $|A - 0| < \epsilon$. On the other hand, we can also find an $n$ for which $0 < |y_n - 0| < \delta$, so the limit $A$ should also satisfy $|A - 1| < \epsilon$.

However, there is no number $A$ that satisfies this simultaneous requirement of $|A - 0| < 1/4$ and $|A - 1| < 1/4$. So, the function has no limit at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand that not just *one* value of $f(x)\in (A-\epsilon, A+\epsilon)$.  But *ALL* $x\in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$ will be that $f(x)\in (A-\epsilon, A+\epsilon)$. It's possible that $x_1 \in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$ and $x_2\in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$ but $f(x_2) \not \in (A-\epsilon, A+\epsilon)$.

Consider $f(x) = 0$ if $x $ is rational and $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is irrational.

Is it possible that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = A$?

The answer is no, the limit doesn't exist.

Let $\epsilon = 0.1$.  If $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = A$ then there would be a $\delta$ so that if $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$ then $|f(x) - A| < 0.1$.

Suppose so.  suppose $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$ is rational. that would mean $|f(x)-A| = |0-A| = |A| < 0.1$ and $-0.1 < A < 0.1$.

But suppose $x_2 \in (-\delta, \delta)$ is irrational.  That wouldd mean $|f(x) -A| = |1-A|=|A-1| < 0.1$ and $-0.1 < A-1 < 0.1$ and $0.9 < A < 1.1$.

But that means $-.1< A< .1$ and $0.9 < A < 1.1$ and that's a contradiction.

So no limit of $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists.

Comment: Also, does $f(a+\delta) =L + \epsilon$, or is this correlation between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ not required?

Comment: we don't know what $f(a+\delta)$ is  and it certainly does not need to equal $L + \epsilon$.  by convention we take *open* intervals so for $f(a + k)$ where $0< k< \delta$ we will have that $L-\epsilon< f(a+k) < L+\epsilon$.  But as to what *exactly* $f(a+k)$ is... we have no more idea than what range it is within.

Comment: A limit exists at $x= a$ if....  we can get $f(x)$ to get "very close" to $A$ by taking $x$ to be "very close to $a$.  that's all.  A limit doesn't exist if $f(x)$ doesn't "settle down" and get close any thing when we get $x$ close to $y$.  In my case $f(x)$ hops between $0$ and $1$ constantly. The "classic example" that Ben Grossman gave (a *really* good answer) of $\sin \frac 1x$.  Is that as $x \to 0$ we have $\frac 1x \to \infty$ so $\sin \frac 1x$ will spin around between $-1$ and $1$ and just bounce through those faster and faster and never settle to anything.